# addMarker Google Maps Option is not displaying

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using a asynctask to query my database and fill an ArrayList of parcels object that contain two doubles, one for longitude and latitude.

```
    ArrayList<parcels> mPoints = new ArrayList<parcels> ();
```

Yet when I add my marker nothing is displayed yet all my debug messages are executed stating that all has ran fine. But when I look there are no markers on my map. I'm new to android and a novice in java.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(mPoints != null){
            //set points
            if(mMap == null){
                Log.d("JakeDebug", "map is null");


            }
            for(int i=0; i < mPoints.size(); i++){
                parcels tmp = mPoints.get(i);
                Log.d("JakeDebug", "marker at " + tmp.longitude +","+ tmp.latitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tmp.latitude, -(tmp.longitude))).title(tmp.name).visible(true));
                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(tmp.latitude, tmp.longitude), 15));
                Log.d("JakeDebug", "Adding marker");

            }

        } else{
            Log.d("JakeDebug", " mPoints is null");


        }
```

My output debug:

```
06-08 09:41:39.599    3165-3182/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ GetPackagesQuery:
06-08 09:41:39.720    3165-3182/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ AddPackageQuery: just before query
06-08 09:41:39.720    3165-3182/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ AddPackageQuery: query = "SELECT name, long, lat FROM _parcels_ where id=1"
06-08 09:41:39.728    3165-3182/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ Login Query: empty = true
06-08 09:41:39.728    3165-3182/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ just after query
06-08 09:41:40.337    3165-3165/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ marker at 38.5539,121.7381
06-08 09:41:40.342    3165-3165/teaminfamous.com.friendsend D/JakeDebug﹕ Adding marker
```

Comment: when are you executing the async task ?

Comment: I'm executing it in my onCreate after the map is set up. I checked if map is set up it is and the array is initialized and have proper items from database inside. Should I not do it in onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to zoom on to that exact spot after realizing I had my numbers flipped and then zooming in I see the marker!

```
 for(int i=0; i < mPoints.size(); i++){
                    parcels tmp = mPoints.get(i);
                    Log.d("JakeDebug", "marker at " + tmp.longitude +","+ tmp.latitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tmp.longitude, -(tmp.latitude))).title(tmp.name).visible(true));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(tmp.longitude, -(tmp.latitude)), 14));
                    Log.d("JakeDebug", "Adding marker");

                }
```

So if your not seeing the marker make sure to move the camera and zoom in on it. That might be the problem, also making sure your numbers are in the right order help!

Comment: I had the same problems with the number flipped and but had zoomed a lot and couldn't find the marker once...

Comment: Yeah haha you think it wud just show the markers without zooming but then again it might and I just don't know what I'm doing haha